# How to get time slot in django for doctor appointment

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have two models Schedule and Appointment.
How can I get the duration of doctor in a different time slots for 15 minutes. I am getting blank in this

models.

```
class Schedule(models.Model):
    doctor=models.ForeignKey(Doctor)
    open=models.TimeField()
    close=models.TimeField()

class Appointment(models.Model):
    patient=models.ForeignKey(Patient)
    doctor=models.ForeignKey(Doctor)
    date=models.DateField()
    time_slot=models.TimeField()
```

Comment: can you explain the problem clearly ?

Comment: suppose there is a doctor x whose online session starts at 10 am in the morning and end at 6pm in the evening,during this time 10 to 6 each session of doctor will be of 15 minutes each.Then how can i show those time slots to patient and how can  patient book that slot.And if a slot is booked no body can book that slot

Comment: what code did you write till this point can you show some sample ?

Comment: i have not done anything so far,but i can only book appointment without time slot,that is where i am getting blank

Comment: ?? can you tell how should i proceed

Comment: writing a answer for the same give me 10 mins

Answer (score 3):

Based on the discussion we had in the comments, I will not provide you the exact code(as you have not done anything yet). But I will explain you different approaches(I can think right now) you can take.

1. Scheduler approach

> First you can convert the timeslot into numbers, like 10:00 becomes 1, 10:15 becomes 1 and so on until the end time and every-time till the end of time(i.e 6pm in your case), store this as array in the timeslot field. Now every-time someone books a slot, just remove the number from the timeslot. Now if someone tires to book the same time slot you see that this number is not available and you don't let them book it or, every-time the page is reloaded you deactivate the slot for the user. The problem is that everyday you have to restore the array(timeslot) to blank before 10:00.(You might need a scheduler like django-beats).

2. More Generic way

> Here what you do is in the table Appointment, make timeslot a number (it is just a number not array, but numbers follow the same pattern like above 10:00 becomes 1, 10:15 becomes 1 etc). Now everytime you load you page for the first time you query that give me all the appointments with this doctor for the day, initially it will be empty, hence you show all the available time slots. Once some user/patient  books a timeslot you just need to create a entry in the Appointment with the patient, doctor, date, timeslot(you can hard code the appointment number on the frontend. like 10 bootstrap cards which show the 15 min timeslot and have different numbers, as you already know timeslot numbers i.e 10:00-> 1, you will receive the timeslot in backend and reserve the slot for the patient.) Now query all the time slots doctor have for the day and don't show the ones which are already booked(appointment table will tell you that).

These are two ways I can think right now, I will add more as I get to realise.
This should give you a direction for now at least.
Ask for details in comments, I will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: thanks for the guidance,i am working on this,thanks for your guidance,i will show my code to you.

Comment: if the answer solves your problem please accept it and upvote it to help others

Comment: OK BUDDY,I WILL DEFINATELY HELP OTHERS TOO

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution for that problem.

```
from django.db import models


class Appointment(models.Model):
    """Contains info about appointment"""

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('doctor', 'date', 'timeslot')

    TIMESLOT_LIST = (
        (0, '09:00 – 09:30'),
        (1, '10:00 – 10:30'),
        (2, '11:00 – 11:30'),
        (3, '12:00 – 12:30'),
        (4, '13:00 – 13:30'),
        (5, '14:00 – 14:30'),
        (6, '15:00 – 15:30'),
        (7, '16:00 – 16:30'),
        (8, '17:00 – 17:30'),
    )

    doctor = models.ForeignKey('Doctor',on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(help_text="YYYY-MM-DD")
    timeslot = models.IntegerField(choices=TIMESLOT_LIST)
    patient_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {} {}. Patient: {}'.format(self.date, self.time, self.doctor, self.patient_name)

    @property
    def time(self):
        return self.TIMESLOT_LIST[self.timeslot][1]


class Doctor(models.Model):
    """Stores info about doctor"""

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    specialty = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.specialty, self.short_name)

    @property
    def short_name(self):
        return '{} {}.{}.'.format(self.last_name.title(), self.first_name[0].upper(), self.middle_name[0].upper())
```

To get the whole source code go to Click [here](https://github.com/Developer-Felix/Doctor---Patient-Scheduler)!